# Sentence structure of (verb + to + infinitive) in japanese

Tags: grammar, translation

Assume I want to say something like :

> I called you to go out.

How a sentence with the same structure would be translated? Is there like a certain pattern or rule to it?

Comment: by "go out" do you mean on a date or just to go about the town? Is this sentence supposed to be during the phone call or an explanation in answer a question afterwards about "why you've been calling?"

Comment: no just go out of town and yes during the phone call but i need something generic for any kind of example like : I went shopping to buy cloths.
I bought a hammer to fix the chair. 
I (verb) to (verb).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

「出かけるためにでんわしました」 or 「出かけるのによびました」 ought to both be valid translations of that. It depends a little on the kind of *going out* that you're doing, but you can generally say "I did X in order to Y" with ために and のに.

http://okwave.jp/qa/q4740693.html has these descriptions (English translations mine):

「ために」は目的の理由？ - ために states the reason why, or the goal, directly.

「のに」は説明？ - のに explains the reason for the call.

I would interpret this as shifting the emphasis, with ために being weighted towards the goal and のに being heavier on the action that was actually taken rather than the reason it was taken.

Comment: The parts you quote are from a question by a non-native speaker, and you don't actually provide translations of them...

Comment: Good point.  I just didn't want to take credit for the text that wasn't mine.